# Resolving Dependency Conflicts in Kaggle Notebook: Incompatibility Issues with Installed Packages ( lightning-flash and torchvision )

Tags: python, pip, kaggle, pytorch-lightning

I am facing dependency conflicts while trying to install certain packages in a Kaggle notebook. The error message indicates that some packages require specific versions of other packages, which are incompatible with the versions already installed in my Kaggle environment. The conflict prevents me from installing required packages like lightning-flash[extra] and torchvision.

The error message lists several packages that have conflicting dependencies, such as click, dill, protobuf, google-api-core, and others.

I am using a Kaggle notebook with limited control over the environment, and it appears that some packages are fixed to specific versions, causing the conflicts. I am unsure about the best way to proceed and would greatly appreciate any guidance or alternative approaches to handle this situation.

---

Code:

```
!pip install lightning-flash[extra]
!pip install lightning-flash
!pip install lightning-flash[image]
from flash.image import SemanticSegmentationData
from flash.image import SemanticSegmentation
!pip install torchvision
from torchvision import transforms as torchvision_transforms
```

Error (Please look Full error in the image attached):
ERROR: pip's dependency resolver does not currently take into account all the packages that are installed. This behaviour is the source of the following dependency conflicts.

---

Code:

```
# Define the normalization transform using the calculated mean and standard deviation
normalize_transform = torchvision_transforms.Normalize(mean=0.5, std=1)
batch_size = 4
resize_transform = torchvision_transforms.Resize(size=(256, 256))
image_transforms = torchvision_transforms.Compose([resize_transform,normalize_transform])
target_transforms = torchvision_transforms.Compose([ resize_transform])

data_module = SemanticSegmentationData.from_folders( train_folder="/kaggle/input/water-body-segmentation-in-satellite-images/Water Bodies Dataset Preprocessed/Water Bodies Dataset Preprocessed/Images", 
                                               train_target_folder="/kaggle/input/water-body-segmentation-in-satellite-images/Scaled Mask Target Image/scale_save_mask_target_image", 
                                                   val_split=0.15, num_classes=2, batch_size=batch_size, transform_kwargs=dict(image_size=(256, 256)) )

data_module.train_transforms = torchvision_transforms.Compose([ image_transforms ])
data_module.val_transforms = torchvision_transforms.Compose([ image_transforms])
data_module.target_transforms = torchvision_transforms.Compose([target_transforms ])
```

Error:

ModuleNotFoundError: Required dependencies not available. Please run: pip install 'lightning-flash[image]'

---

I have tried multiple approaches to resolve the issue, including installing the required packages using pip, creating a virtual environment, and ignoring the warnings. However, none of these solutions have worked so far.

Installing Required Packages: We attempted to install the required packages (lightning-flash[extra] and torchvision) using the standard !pip install command. However, the installation failed due to conflicts with existing package versions.

Virtual Environment: We considered creating a virtual environment using the virtualenv package, but it turns out that virtual environments are not required in Kaggle notebooks as the environment is already isolated.

Ignoring Warnings: We observed multiple dependency conflict warnings but opted not to ignore them as it might lead to incorrect behavior or errors in the code execution.

Alternative Package Versions: We tried to specify compatible versions for conflicting packages (click, dill, protobuf, google-api-core, etc.) in an attempt to avoid conflicts. However, this approach did not fully resolve the issue.

Test in Local Environment: We suggested replicating the environment and dependencies in a local setup to check for compatibility issues and verify if the conflicting packages can coexist in the same environment.

Answer (score 2):

You can try using conda installations in kaggle. Example:

```
!conda install pytorch::torchvision
```

You can try installing spesific versions of the libraries that are known to be compatible(you can google search for them) Example:

```
!pip install torchvision==0.15.0
```

You can try reinstalling the packages or reinstalling a spesific version like this:

```
!pip uninstall torchvision
```

then

```
!pip install torchvision==0.15.0
```

Important sidenote:
Checking what libraries and versions are installed in your kaggle enviroment.
You can use

```
!pip freeze
```

Example:

[image]